# how to set value for translateX with css in typescript

Tags: css, typescript

I am using typescript to set a style of a element dynamically, this is the code looks like:

```
export function showTranslateButton(e: MouseEvent){
  let translateBtn = document.getElementById("translate-btn");
  if(translateBtn){
    translateBtn.style.width ="40px";  
    translateBtn.style.backgroundColor="red";
    translateBtn.style.height="50px";
    translateBtn.style.transform.translateX=e.pageX;
  }
}
```

when I set the `translateX` value, shows error that:

```
Property 'translateX' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)
```

what should I do to set the translateX value? I have tried this:

```
translateBtn.style.transform="translate("+e.pageX+ ","+ e.pageY+")";
```

it compile success but the style did not add success, the style did not contain the transform block.

Comment: could not use the translateX. @ABOS

Comment: e.pageX does not have unit?

Comment: yes, that's the problem, did not contain the unit.@ABOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just add "+'px'" add the end of "e.pageX".
Because the value should be a number + the unit (px,rem,precent ...)

Tell me if it helps you or not.